# What pattern to use in paper-input to decimal number?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I would like a pattern for decimal number in paper-input for following outpus:

```
 111.111,11 >>> true 
 111,11 >>> true 
 0,11 >>> true
```

I am using the following pattern:

```
"^([0-9]{1,3}\.)?[0-9]{1,3}\,[0-9]{2}$?"
```

in the code:

```
<paper-input type="number" pattern="^([0-9]{1,3}\.)?[0-9]{1,3}\,[0-9]{2}$?" auto-validate error-message="Não é um número válido!" label="Faturamento Anual" value="{{parametro.faturamentoAnual}}"><div prefix>R$</div></paper-input>
```

But when I type `0,11` and return `false` with the error-message.

Is there a different pattern to decimal number in paper-input that works?

Comment: Your regex [works for me](http://rubular.com/r/mEh9EqAbeT). Also, you don't need to escape the literal comma, and I believe there should be no trailing `?` in the regex.

Comment: Yes, works in rubular. But it does not works in Polymer `paper-input` (I am using Dart lang). It may be a bug!

Comment: What is the intention of the `?` at the end?

Answer (score 2):

The `?` at the end of your regex doesn't make sense to me.
I tried it without the `?` and it worked fine. 
I also had to remove `type=number` to be able to enter anything at all.
A plain `<input type="number">` doesn't allow `,` or `.` as well.

Comment: Ok, I found an example with `?`. I get out it. I remove `type=number` too and work better.